# What exactly THREE.Math.mapLinear do?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've seen an example program, in that to place the position of the Sphere they are doing some mathematical calculations. In that I've seen `THREE.Math.mapLinear()` is being used. If I pass the parameters as:

```
var x = THREE.Math.mapLinear(-70.16, -150, 150, 0, 1366);
```

then the value of `x` is showing 363.51.

Please can anyone explain what exactly happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `mapLinear` function](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5c7e0df9b100ba40cdcaaf530196290e16c34858/src/math/Math.js#L60) takes two ranges of numbers (`a1`-`a2` and `b1`-`b2`), and an offset (`x`):

```
mapLinear: function ( x, a1, a2, b1, b2 ) {
    return b1 + ( x - a1 ) * ( b2 - b1 ) / ( a2 - a1 );
}
```

It works out how far through the range of `a` that `x` is, and calculates the equivalent position in `b` and returns it.

With your input, `-70.16` is *roughly one quarter* (23.387%) of the way through the range `-150` to `150`.  The function returns `363.51`, which is the equivalent *roughly one quarter* (23.387%) of the way through the range `0` to `1366`.